# What python code is necessary to convert the integers of a bitcoin public key into the proper hex version thereof?

Tags: public-key, python, encoding

If I get a public key of two integers, x and y values what code is necessary to convert them into their hex versions without any additional letters, or numbers?  This is half a Python programming question and half a bitcoin question though I think it is better asked here due to the familiarity with bitcoin requirements.

Pseudo code:

> xpublickey = 20091690549896866803343277351761137627937393619088856147056855893222768847187
>
> ypublickey = 69823032225116710867248379519530157435196049639426167980995931003755153241086
>
> hexpublickey = "04" + hex(xpublickey) + hex(ypublickey)

I don't know what code is necessary to turn it into (as the above code does not work):

> 042C6B7E6DA7633C8F226891CC7FA8E5EC84F8EACC792A46786EFC869A408D29539A5E6F8DE3F71C0014E8EA71691C7B41F45C083A074FEF7AB5C321753BA2B3FE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> y = hex(xPublicKey).rstrip("L").lstrip("0x")
>
> z = hex(yPublicKey).rstrip("L").lstrip("0x")
>
> hexpublickey = "04" + y + z